# Draw a curve of the Cycloid

Tags: c#, winforms, geometry, zedgraph

Good time of day. It is necessary to draw a graph of the cycloids, the radius is specified by the user. Managed to paint only half of the period, I do not understand what it is.

Code'm applying.

My function:

```
return r * Math.Acos((r - y) / r) - Math.Sqrt(2 * r * y - Math.Pow(y, 2));
```

And my Main part:

```
GraphPane pane = zedGraph.GraphPane;

            pane.CurveList.Clear();

            PointPairList list = new PointPairList();

            double r = 20;
            double xmax = 50;

            for (double y = 0; y < xmax; y+=0.5)
            {

                list.Add(CountIt(y, r), y);
            }

            LineItem myCurve = pane.AddCurve("Cycloid", list, Color.Red, SymbolType.None);

            zedGraph.AxisChange();

            zedGraph.Invalidate();
```

[image]

Apparently it is necessary to consider the situation when y>2r, or that should be several possible x? I do not understand how to get out of the situation.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ TAG your question correctly!

Comment: I see 2 possible Versions here: 1st: your Points are not what you think they are (RADIAN / DEGREE? miscalculation? xmax too low?); 2nd: zedGraph cannot handle that kind of data very well;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simpler to use parametric equations (with `t=0..2*Pi` for one period):

```
x = r * (t - sin(t))
y = r * (1 - cos(t))
```

If you want to continue using Cartesian equation x(y) - change limit for `y`   to correct value `2 * r` and mirror the second part like this:

```
 for (double y = 0; y < 2 * r; y+=0.5)
        {
            list.Add(CountIt(y, r), y);
        }
 for (double y = 2 * r; y >= 0; y-=0.5)
        {
            list.Add(2 * Pi * r - CountIt(y, r), y);
        }
```

If you need to draw few periods, limiting xmax:

```
 p = 0;
 while true do
 {
     for (double y = 0; y < 2 * r; y+=0.5)
            {   x = 2 * Pi * r * p + CountIt(y, r);
                if (x > xmax)
                    break; 
                list.Add(x, y);
            }
     for (double y = 2 * r; y >= 0; y-=0.5)
            {
               x =   2 * Pi * r * (p + 1) - CountIt(y, r);
                if (x > xmax)
                    break; 
               list.Add(x, y);
            }
     p++;
 }
```

Comment: And how you can continue to build, which is the next turn? For example, if the user specifies where to draw the cycloid. Xmax = 150

Comment: Just repeat the same loops, adding `(2 * Pi * r * p)` where p is period.number (starting from 0-th), stopping when x reaches xmax

Comment: May I add to the answer?) I am no mathematician

Comment: Managed to do it myself, but your help was way :)